'asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto.UUID' object has no attribute 'replace'
I'm building a fastAPI application. I have a Psotgres DB where i write and read data from. I'm using SQLAlchemy to interact with my Postgres Database. Here is my model:
import uuid
from db.database import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Boolean, DateTime, func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        unique=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
    full_name = Column(String, nullable=True)
    password = Column(String, nullable=True) 
    email = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now(), nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User {self.email}>'

UserTable = User.__table__

And I'm trying to run a query like this:
from models.user import User as UserDB
import uuid
from db.database import database
from datetime import datetime
from asyncpg.exceptions import UniqueViolationError
from typing import Optional

async def get_user_by_email(email: str) -> Optional[UserDB]:
    query = UserTable.select().where(UserTable.c.email == email)
    try:
        user_record = await database.fetch_one(query)
        if user_record:
            user_dict = dict(user_record)
            return UserDB(**user_dict)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    return None

This result in the below error:
Error: 'asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto.UUID' object has no attribute 'replace'


Turns out as_uuid=True was not needed https://github.com/python-gino/gino/issues/712
